# What does the -o- flag do for CURL?

Tags: curl

Node version manager's [CURL instructions](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installing-and-updating) says to use this command:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash
```

What does the -o- do? The closest I am able to find while Googling is the -o flag in [this documentation](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-o).

Comment: `The - after -o tells curl that the output file is stdout.` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642479/what-is-curl-o

Comment: AND that stdout is then redirected into `sh`, whee the commands will be executed. To see what is happening, you can change `| sh` to `>/tmp/myScript.sh; cat|less|more /tmp/myScript.sh`. (chose one of cat|less|more). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

quoting the curl documentation:

> -o, --output
>
> Write output to  instead of stdout. (...) Specifying the output as '-' (a single dash) passes the output to stdout.

`-o-` is equivalent to `-o -` and means `write the output to stdout` (writing to stdout is the default anyway, but it allows you to be explicit about writing to stdout, instead of writing to curl default, which happens to be stdout). functionally, `-o-` does *nothing*.

if you're not familar with stdin/stdout/stderr, perhaps read wikipedia's entry on the topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)